# Delete or edit row in database using a button in php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'd like to make a button, you know like the basic html button but I want it at every end of the rows in my table. I want it to be able to when clicked to delete rows in my database or edit them

I'm a newbie, remember... That's why I'm calling for help

Here are my codes

exempel.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$root = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dbname";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $root, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT fnamn, snamn FROM nametable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     echo "<table><tr><th>Name</th></tr>";

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         echo "<tr><td>" . $row["fnamn"]. " " . $row["snamn"]. "</td></tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
} else {
     echo "No results";
}

$conn->close();
?>  

</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<html>
<body>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO nametable (fnamn, snamn)
VALUES
('$_POST[fnamn]','$_POST[snamn]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "Database updated with submitted data";

mysql_close($con)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test this form</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Förnamn: <input type="text" name="fnamn" /><br><br>
Efternamn: <input type="text" name="snamn" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If you try the exempel.php, I want some button/s that can edit or delete that row

Just so you all know, I edited some of the texts and names in the codes to make it readable for you guys, otherwise it's in swedish. Perhaps I forgot to edit one or more names

```
snamn= lastname
fnamn= firstname
dbname= namnelle
nametable= namntabell
```

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: If you want to use php for row deleting/editing have a look at Ajax. You will find plenty of examples. Then come back with the doubts/issues you will find

Comment: You're using `mysqli` in the first bit of code, which is mostly fine, but the second one uses the awful `mysql_query` interface. You really should standardize on something that will work consistently, not have each file as its own independent little kingdom.

Comment: you want to add button in every row?

Comment: yes @ShafiqulIslam

Comment: @tadman problem is that I am just doing this for fun, I am not going to get exploited or anything because this is just for testing purposes, having a local server up just trying things out.
I know people can inject it, no problems for me, not gonna have it up for views.

Comment: @LelioFaieta I was wondering if it was possible only, I'm not interested in putting in some javascript into this

Comment: If you're learning that's fine, even if just for fun. The idea is to do it properly so you don't create a mess. Using prepared statements with placeholder values results in cleaner, easier to read code that doesn't waste a lot of your time tracking down SQL syntax errors.

Comment: @tadman just for testing purposes :) I know it's a bit ugly with multiple files

Comment: It's not that it's multiple files, it's that you're using two completely different SQL interfaces here and making a mess of things. It's no fun when you have to fight against that all the time.

Comment: @tadman sorry, I'm really a newbie to these thing, I'm still learning

Comment: check my answer , if you want to more then i will

Comment: No need to be sorry. Just saying try and keep your life simple and you'll have a better time with what you're learning. Only looking out for you.

Comment: @tadman REALLY appreciate your help, but to be honest I don't quite understand the most of it. If I maybe had a bit more knowledge I could've used your form of helping and made those buttons :)

Comment: Doing bare PHP to make applications can be a harrowing journey, there's a ton of stuff you absolutely must learn to make any headway. If you're looking to be productive and you're willing to invest a bit of time in learning I'd strongly recommend looking at a development framework. There's many to pick form in the PHP world, but [Laravel](https://laravel.com) is particularly beginner friendly. It does a lot of the heavy lifting so you can focus on things like what your button does rather than how to make a button in the first place. It's the more civilized way to make apps.

Comment: btw, why are you using `mysqli_` in one piece of code, then switching to `mysql_` in the other?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry, it's a complilation of codes from different sites which I just edited to make it work with my database
Didn't know the difference between mysqli and mysql, I'll edit it directly, should I use mysqli or mysql?

Comment: @tadman I'll look into Laravel, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code, add code for php file which you want to , something like this . in edit php file you can get data

```
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$lname = $_GET['sname'];
```

then you can do which you want

```
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["fnamn"]. " " . $row["snamn"]. "<a href='edit.php?type=add&fname=".$row["fnamn"]."&sname=". $row["snamn"]."'>Add</a><a href='edit.php?type=edit&fname=".$row["fnamn"]."&sname=". $row["snamn"]."'>Edit</a><a href='edit.php?type=deletefname=".$row["fnamn"]."&sname=". $row["snamn"]."'>Delete</a></td></tr>";
 }
```

if you want to add then your edit file like this

```
  print_r($_GET);
  $fname = $_GET['fname'];
 $sname = $_GET['sname'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO nametable (fnamn, snamn)
  VALUES
 ('$fname','$sname')";
```

in edit page there are get data type check this value then take action.
if $_GET['type] == 'add'
then add code for insert , if edit then edit code etc

this is your edit page

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Test this form</h1>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  Förnamn: <input type="text" name="fnamn" value="<?=$_GET['fname']?>"    /><br><br>
 Efternamn: <input type="text" name="snamn" value="<?=$_GET['sname']?>" /><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Appreciate you trying to help me but I don't quite understand :/
I added everything you wrote but when I open edit.php it's empty on my browser

Comment: just add this line your edit.php file
print_r($_GET);

Comment: then if file path and file exit then you will see all get data must

Comment: Added it, not quite doing the things I'd wanted it to do, appreciate your help though :)

Comment: <?php
print_r($_GET);
$fnamn = $_GET['fnamn'];
$snamn = $_GET['snamn'];
$sql="INSERT INTO namntabell (fnamn, snamn)
  VALUES
 ('$fnamn','$snamn')";
?>

Comment: have you edit.php file? if have then remove all code and print it

<?php 
print_r($_GET); and link add link in first page then go to edit .php file

Comment: the OP wrote: *"Delete or edit row"* - I doubt they want to INSERT here. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: It seems to work a bit, but I don't understand what the Add linktext should do

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, I think it's a bit of communication errors here

Comment: check my update code and in edit page there are get data type check this value then take action

Comment: What do you mean by adding this lname
I had snamn and fnamn

Comment: i think this is not major issue, you can change it when you want

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b63355ef31f84f0f1e75e7724246bfb6
This is how example.php looks like

Not quite buttons, just text working as links and the links don't quite do anything more than guide you to edit.php where it shows you the row you clicked on

Comment: i am not clear , you want to link text dynamic? or something?

Comment: What I want is three buttons after the rows
Edit and delete

Where edit can edit the row and delete deletes the entire row

Comment: echo "<tr><td>" . $row["fnamn"]. " " . $row["snamn"]. "<a href='edit.php?type=add&fname=".$row["fnamn"]."&lname=". $row["snamn"]."'>&nbsp;".$row["fnamn"]."&nbsp;</a><a href='edit.php?type=edit&fname=".$row["fnamn"]."&lname=". $row["snamn"]."'>&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;</a><a href='edit.php?type=deletefname=".$row["fnamn"]."&lname=". $row["snamn"]."'>&nbsp;Delete&nbsp;</a></td></tr>";

Comment: when you click edit button then in edit.php you need to check that which your fname and sname then add mysql update code and more , if you want to go to new file then update link for edit and delete link

Comment: I'm going to be completely honest with you, I don't quite understand a lot of what you are saying, we have communication errors here but I do appreciate you trying to help me.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/9ab1ec2fe088126acb07133e75a57406

This is what I want it to be like
An edit button which edits the values in the rows
An delete button which deletes the row

Comment: do you find any solution or try me?

Comment: @Shafiqul Islam You can try to make one, if you know what I mean

Comment: ok but need final conformation that there will be two icon 1. edit and 2. delete . if click edit then action edit and click delete then action delete?